# Restlet createInboundRoot invoked when app run as Eclipse/J2SE but not as maven jetty:run-war

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, restlet, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a simple Restlet app that works fine when run as a J2SE application from Eclipse, but when packaged as a war and run with "mvn jetty:run-war" (jetty-maven-plugin), the Application.createInboundRoot method does not get invoked and thus no routes are configured.

The pertinent error message appears to be

```
WARNING: A filter was executed without a next Restlet attached to it.
```

You can see from the console output that in the J2SE case ModspaceRestletApplication.createInboundRoot is invoked and in the J2EE case that method is not invoked. Why not?

Run as J2SE (Eclipse->Run As->Java Application).

Test by hitting the URL:

```
http://localhost:8182/modspace/users/fred/entries
```

Correctly formed response is returned and console output is:

```
In ModspaceRestApplication.ctor
Mar 25, 2014 2:41:15 PM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.HttpServerHelper start
INFO: Starting the internal HTTP server on port 8182
In ModspaceRestApplication.createInboundRoot
```

Run as war from command line using 'mvn jetty:run-war".

Test by hitting URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/modspace/users/fred/entries
```

Browser sees

```
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
```

and console output is:

```
2014-03-25 14:42:27.125:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.0.M0
2014-03-25 14:42:31.507:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@6307c51a{/,file:/Users/wilma/eclipse-workspace/modspace-rest/target/modspace-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/,AVAILABLE}{/Users/wilma/eclipse-workspace/modspace-rest/target/modspace-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
2014-03-25 14:42:31.509:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2014-03-25 14:42:32.004:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@459c745a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
In ModspaceRestApplication.ctor
2014-03-25 14:42:50.964:INFO:/:qtp721530251-44: RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching application: com.merck.modspace.rest.ModspaceRestletApplication@74e1d431 to URI: /modspace
Mar 25, 2014 2:42:50 PM org.restlet.routing.Filter doHandle
WARNING: A filter was executed without a next Restlet attached to it.
Mar 25, 2014 2:42:51 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2014-03-25    14:42:50    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 8080    GET  /modspace/users/fred/entries   -   500 365 -   20  http://localhost:8080     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36   -
```

Tools:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_51
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app id="ModspaceWS" version="2.4"  
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee  
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">  
   <display-name>Modspace RESTlet web service</display-name>  

   <!-- Restlet adapter -->  
   <servlet>  
      <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>  
      <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <!-- Application class name -->
            <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.merck.modspace.rest.ModspaceRestletApplication</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </servlet>  

   <!-- Catch all requests -->  
   <servlet-mapping>  
      <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>  
      <url-pattern>/modspace/*</url-pattern>  
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.merck.modspace.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>modspace-rest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ModSpaceWebService</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-restlet</id>
      <name>Restlet framework repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>mvnrepository</id>
      <url>https://mvnrepository.com//</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Restlet Application class:

```
import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class ModspaceRestletApplication extends Application {

    Router router;

    public ModspaceRestletApplication() {
        System.out.println("In ModspaceRestApplication.ctor");
        //this.setInboundRoot(this.createInboundRoot());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        // Create a root router
        router = new Router(getContext());

        System.out.println("In ModspaceRestApplication.createInboundRoot");

        // Attach the handlers to the root router
        router.attach("/users/{user}", UserResource.class);
        router.attach("/users/{user}/entries", ModelResource.class);

        return router;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a new Restlet component and add a HTTP server connector to it
        Component component = new Component();
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

        // Then attach it to the local host
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("/modspace", new ModspaceRestletApplication());

        // Now, let's start the component!
        // Note that the HTTP server connector is also automatically started.
        component.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This now works. I believe the problem was due to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

which should be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Notice groupID was wrong and version was old.